# Is there a way to create a table without grid-lines?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a table that will later be used as a popup when a link in my imported sql table is clicked on. Example of the table for comprehensive sake is attached with this post

I have tried creating a table, and did research on how to create a table like that of the picture

This is what I have done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table style="width:30%">
  <tr>
    <th>PT</th>
    <th>OT</th>
    <th>SLP</th>
    <th>NSG</th>
    <th>NTA</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>11</td>
    `<td>9</td>`
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html> </pre>
```

I expect the output to be the same as of the one in the image posted

[This is what I am trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKSiV.png)

Comment: `table, th, td { none; }`, maybe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables, by default, do not have grid lines. Here are the lines that are creating the table grid lines:

```
<style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black; /*  <<===== this one  */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

Change it to:

```
<style>
    table, th, td {
    border-collapse: collapse; /*  You can keep this line or not, optional */
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

---

#### Update:

To answer your question in the comment, I would use two tables and put a DIV around them. Then, put the border around the DIV.  If you make the div a little wider than the table, then you can add another DIV inside and position it as absolute, from the top/right.

Note that in order to use `position:absolute` on the inner div, the parent div must be something other than the default `position:static` - so I would recommend `position:relative` since it is almost the same as static.

To round the corners of the border, use `border-radius` *(top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left)*

```css
table{border-collapse: collapse;}
#tblDiv{position:relative;width:25vw;border:1px solid #aaa;border-radius:10px;}
th, td {
  width: 6vw;
  padding: .5vw;
  text-align: center;
}

#rbrdDiv{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;width:3vw;height:100%;border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;background:blueviolet;}
```

```html
<div id="tblDiv">
  <div id="rbrdDiv"></div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>PT</th>
      <th>OT</th>
      <th>SLP</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>NSG</th>
      <th>NTA</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can create the left arrow by using the `::before` pseudo-selector, and I leave that as an exercise for you to do. Here are some references for how to do it. If you cannot do it within ten minutes, post another comment and I will assist.

https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/

https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

---

References:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/

Comment: how to I add values like the one displayed in the picx?

Comment: You are amazing!! Thank you. You have been a great resources!!

Comment: #tiprbrdDiv:after {
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-right-color: #ffffff ;
 border-width: 25px;
 margin-top: -37px;
}

#tiprbrdDiv::before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 36px;
 margin-top: -36px;
} This is not showing the arrow. My question is would you recommend creating a class that wraps around rbrdDiv id, and apply the the ::after to the created div. I also had other ideas about creating two arrows but that sounds complicated enough. Thank you in advances

Comment: Tied up for a bit... My suggestion is to accept a correct answer for this question (to close the question and reward the most helpful answer), and open a new question for this inquiry. Doing so is always the fastest, most expedient route to getting answers ***quickly*** - and also supports SO's underlying model by quickly rewarding answers. Remember, it costs zero to accept an answer (in fact, ***you also*** get 2 rep) and/or to upvote helpful answers, and those answering appreciate it, so it makes sense. *Meilleurs voix!*

Answer (score 0):

You have CSS that is putting the border on there. remove the border 1px solid black. I hope I am answering this correct

```
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
```

}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}